# In nautilus, how to show context menu on focused file when press Menu Key?

Tags: linux, windows-explorer, nautilus

In Windows Explorer, if a file is focused, press [Menu Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) on keyboard, context menu will show on top of the file.  But in Nautilus, the same action shows context menu where the mouse cursor is.  That's a bit annoying.  Is there anyway to make it work like Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug in Nautlius](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=102666) and fixing it would require modifying its source code.

Note that while the context menu is *positioned* next to the mouse cursor, the options in the menu apply to the highlighted file, not the file currently under the mouse pointer.